# How to change background image of Rainmeter system.ini

Tags: windows-10, desktop-gadget, widgets, rainmeter, background

[Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net) is a useful tool for creating desktop widgets. I'm using system.ini skin, it's transparent but I want some opaque background.

The system.ini file has these lines:

```
[Rainmeter]
; This section contains general settings that can be used to change how Rainmeter behaves.
Update=1000
Background=#@#Background.png
; #@# is equal to Rainmeter\Skins\illustro\@Resources
BackgroundMode=3
BackgroundMargins=0,34,0,14
```

There's no 'Skins' directory under 'Rainmeter', it's under 'Rainmeter/Default'.
I found the location of 'Background.png', put another image in there, and changed the line 'Background=' in system.ini but didn't work; the system skin just disappeared!

Tried another solution, put the new background image in the same folder with system.ini, and I changed background (in system.ini file) to this:

```
Background=MyBackground.png
```

But it's not working too. Any simple steps to change background for a skin please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out how.

**Rainmeter has 2 directories** after installation:

- Application installation folder, for example:
  `C:\Program Files\Rainmeter`
- Data folder, for example:
  `C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Rainmeter`

**The installation folder** is know during installation steps, the **data folder** can be found as following:

- Right-click Rainmeter icon in system tray
- Click 'Edit settings'
- Right in the first few lines of the settings file, there is a line starting with:
  `SkinPath=`
  That is the correct path to 'Skins' folder, not the one in application folder, the one in application folder is `Rainmeter\Defaults\Skins` which it not where to modify the widgets and data for widgets.

**Change the default background to opaque**:

- Go to skin path folder
- Go to `illustro\@Resources` inside it
- Copy `Background.png` to `Background2.png`
- Open the file Background2.png with mspaint
- Ctrl+S to save (this makes it opaque, coz mspaint can't save transparency)
- Right-click on a skin UI, choose 'Edit skin'
- Change `Background=#@#Background.png` to `Background=#@#Background2.png`
- Right-click on the skin UI again, choose 'Refresh skin'
- Done!